# How to use Bitmaps as Icon in MenuItem

Tags: android, xml, bitmap, menu, icons

I can´t seem to be able to use Bitmaps (specifically .png files) as Icons in a MenuItem, what is the right way to do it?

I tried referencing the Bitmap directly in the xml but also referencing a BitMapDrawable xml which in itself was referencing the Bitmap.

The item in the navigation.xml bitmap_name refers to either the bitmap or the BitmapDrawable xml

```xml
<item
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:icon="@drawable/bitmap_name"
        android:title="@string/title" />
```

the BitmapDrawable xml. Here the bitmap_name refers to the bitmap.

```xml
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/bitmap_name">
</bitmap>
```

I expect the bitmap to be shown as the Icon but I only get a green Circle.
[A image of the actual result](https://i.imgur.com/MBQ5Ae6.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your Ong file directly in the drawable folder

[image]

Then, just set the icon

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/id"
    android:icon="@drawable/error"
    android:title="@string/title"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
 />
```

No need to use `BitmapDrawable`

Comment: It is in the drawable folder but it still doesnt work

Comment: Weird. I do it and it works. Wich sdk are you targetting?

Comment: Target SDK: API 27: Android 8.1 (Oreo)